# Logic level shifting

Tags: logic-level

I want to interface 12 VDC rated [WS2815B addressable LED strip](http://www.world-semi.com/DownLoadFile/138) with a 3.3 VDC microcontroller.

I am having difficulty finding a logic level shifter which translates 3.3 V to 12 V. Data rate is significantly high and hence fast rise and fall times are required. Timings are as below:

[image]

How do I tackle this problem?

Two things come to my mind:

1) Maybe there is a part which will do the job and I am not aware of it.

2) I need to implement logic level conversion circuit using basic components. - In this regard, I cam across some circuits as shown below:

[image: logic level shifter]

However on further reading, I found that these circuits can't achieve the fast rise and fall times required by ws2815b. Is there a better way which can solve my problem?

Comment: You misunderstand what you have, and how to drive it. It is powered by 12 volts, and the logic signals are 5 volts, and need to come from a MPU or Arduino or Raspberry Pi, as it takes complex command streams to sequence through colors and brightness levels. Each LED is a module with a serial interface, not a bare bones LED. Read the fine details please.

Comment: @sparky256 - I do understand that it's not barebone LED. It requires command streams for color settings. Page 2 lists absolute max ratings where 9.5V to 13.5V is mentioned. I believe it means the strip needs 12 V as supply. On page 3 however, it mentions electrical characteristics. In parenthesis, it mentions VDD as 4.5V to 5.5V and then logic high is mentioned as 0.7 VDD. This is what is confusing me.

Answer (score 1):

THe WS2815B operates on Vcc= 5V supply logic levels from 0.3 to 0.7 x 5V  not the LED 12V supply.  This means it is similar to the 5V CMOS Schmitt trigger input.

The LED supply is called \$V_{DD}\$ and intended for automotive 12V supply voltages or +9.5~+13.5

The Din Data port operates off \$V_{CC}\$ which is internally regulated and brought out for a Cap to added as an option.  Check Pin1. It must be 5V.

Pins 3,4,6 are 5V logic level signals.  BI on pin 6  is grounded only on the 1st chip.

======

The datasheet is a bit unconventional lacking in some details, so this confusion is expected.

They could have included something like this.
[image]

Perhaps they assumed too much.

The chip ought to have diode clamps to internal 5V on the input from the 10k Pullup you used.

**Your design looks ok except the pullup should be to pin 1 = 5V**

Depending on the cable capacitance the 10k may need to be lowered towards 1k.

---

I added in BLUE

[image]

Comment: You changed your name again? Geeze...

Comment: I wore many hats too.

Comment: Page 2 lists absolute max ratings where 9.5V to 13.5V is mentioned. I believe it means the strip needs 12 V as supply. On page 3 however, it mentions electrical characteristics. In parenthesis, it mentions VDD as 4.5V to 5.5V and then logic high is mentioned as 0.7 VDD. This is what is confusing me.

Comment: I feel that logic level should be according to 12 V. LED has DIN and DOUT pins. It also has a waveform correction feature where the data waveform is corrected before passing to the next LED. When I give a 5V logic to the first LED powered by 12V, it automatically raises the voltage levels to approx 10V for the next LED.